# EmberJS calling controller function within #each

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to call a controller function inside a #each template to check if the model is selected. This needs to receive the model for each loop iteration.

jsbin is here http://emberjs.jsbin.com/bemos/4/edit

I've tried using the following template, but adding a parameter to {{controller.selected}} results in ember throwing an exception, or not doing anything (the result seems to be different in jsbin).

```
{{#each model}}
    <li><a hres="#" {{action "clickItem" this}}>{{label}} -- selected is {{controller.selected name}} </a></li>
{{/each}}
```

My function in the controller looks as follows

```
selected: function(id) {
    var list = this.get("selectedList");
    console.log("Checking sel for", id);
    if(list.contains(id))
        return true;
    return false;
}.property("selectedList")
```

In the jsbin, I expect to be able to click on the "Hello 1"/"Hello 2" elements, and this should change the part of the text that says "selected is false" to true. It should also update the number of items selected in the bottom. Currently, this shows 1 item is selected (since the default is selectedList:["2"]) however "Hello 2" says "selected is false" - this should say "true".

(I should add I'm pretty new to EmberJS as have been working with ExtJS for a few years!).
Thanks

Comment: does it need to be selected or could you set a selected property yourself? ala the completed property in the ember tutorial on emberjs

Comment: I need to be able to select it with an action (as in the jsbin), so it's this part of the code that's not working. Just to be sure I haven't missed a tutorial, can you paste the link? Thanks.

Comment: this tutorial here - http://emberjs.com/guides/getting-started/displaying-a-models-completeness/ - and this is the page where they talk about setting a property, which they do with an action

Comment: Thanks. In this tutorial the isCompleted field is in the model - I'm trying to use a controller function.

Comment: Its a property in the model triggered by a controller function. Im just offering an alternative and wondering does it need to be done this way or could it be handled another way?

Comment: Thanks - I appreciate the thought. My thinking is that this sort of transient data shouldn't be in the model - it's more part of the controller. That's my thinking anyway - that said, getting it working right now is more important :)

Answer (score 1):

Do you really have a problem in code ? I guess no, since your bin is working fine and even clickItem is working as well. In your local environment where you are facing this issue, I think you are not using same version of handlebars and ember. Please check if you are using below,

```
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://builds.handlebarsjs.com.s3.amazonaws.com/handlebars-v1.3.0.js"></script>
  <script src="http://builds.emberjs.com/tags/v1.6.1/ember.js"></script>
```

**Update 1** -

Here is the bin I tried to update - http://emberjs.jsbin.com/veqoqocu/1/edit
Its not fully functioning but fixes some issue.

There are multiple problems,

1. You should use ArrayController for lists, redesign your example otherwise selected property will never work the way you want. Here is a good example - http://emberjs.com/guides/controllers/representing-multiple-models-with-arraycontroller/
2. push & pop needs to be pushObject and popObject
3. computer property on array works like - }.property('selectedList.[]')

Comment: Thanks. Ember and Handlebars are the same version as you list above. I do have JQ 2 though. However I'm surprised that you say the jsbin is working? It certainly doesn't work when I run it. When I load, it tells me 1 item is selected, but both show false and clicking on them doesn't change this. Currently there is no passing of any parameter to the controller (since this causes problems) so did you change something to get the select status to update?

Comment: Ok, so you mean your real problem in not error but something else ? Can you please what exactly needs to be fixed in jsbin, I didnt see any error for sure.

Comment: Ok, sorry. In the jsbin, you should be able to click on the "Hello 1"/"Hello 2" elements, and it should change the part of the test that says "selected is *false*" to true. It should also update the number of items selected in the bottom. Currently, this shows 1 item is selected (since the default is selectedList:["2"]) however "Hello 2" says "selected is false" - this should say "true". Thanks.

Comment: Thanks - that really helped, and solved a number of the issues (and I learnt some more :) ), but still leaves me with the original issue that I can't seem to pass the id into the controller when checking for the selection.

Comment: You cant. Because you are using Object controller where your model is an array. You need to define a ArrayController and then set its itemController property with the instance of an ObjectController then you will get access to id of the individual object in your computed property.